# How to serialize the object of type DateTimeFormatInfo?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, datetimeformatinfo

I want to serialize the object of type DatetimeFormatInfo.

I tried the following code:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yy";
xs = new XmlSerializer(dateTimeFormat.GetType());
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Setting.xml");
xs.Serialize(sw, dateTimeFormat);
```

But it throws the below exception.

> **System.InvalidOperationException** was unhandled.
>   There was an error generating the XML document.
>   The type **System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar** was not expected.
>   Use the **XmlInclude** or **SoapInclude** attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Is anything I need to add for serializing DateTimeFormatInfo?

Comment: The serializer is going to traverse the object graph which may contain objects that are not serializable. I would recommend serializing the date pattern instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include in the `XmlSerializer` a list of addictional object types to serialize.
In your case, you need to add the object type `System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar`.

```
        System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateTimeFormat = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
        dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yy";

        // Add here all the extra types you need to serialize
        Type[] extraTypes = new Type[] { typeof(System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar) };

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(dateTimeFormat.GetType(), extraTypes);
        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\testso.xml");
        xs.Serialize(sw, dateTimeFormat);
```